# ajax post is empty(Empty String in Database)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I have a Problem with my ajax-Code .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var activeTD;
    $(".td_test").click(function() {
        $("#bModal").modal('show');
        activeTD = this;
        return false;

    }); 
    $("#ajaxtest").submit(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"InsertServlet",
            dataType: "text",

        })
        .done(function(data){
            alert(data);
            $(activeTD).text(data);
        });
    });
});
```

`alert(data)` opens a Dialog but its Empty, which means that `data` is either an empty String or not available.Can you help me out with this?

If it helps, this is my Servlet Code :

```
public class InsertServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected  void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException {
    processRequest(request,response);   
}

protected void doGeT(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException {
    processRequest(request,response);   
}

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    String name="";
    if(request.getParameter("submitdata") != null) {


        if(request.getParameter("getdata") != null) {
            name += request.getParameter("getdata");

        }
    }
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(name);
    out.close();

    String URL ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    String username = "root";
    String pw= "root";

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs =null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,username,pw);


        stmt = con.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO ver(TName) VALUES(?);");
        stmt.setString(1,name);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        stmt.clearParameters();
        stmt.close();
    }catch(Exception e) {

    }finally {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you check the value of the `name` variable in your servlet?

Comment: You have no `data:` parameter in your `$.ajax()` call. So `request.getParameter("getdata")` won't find anything.

Comment: getData is the Name of my <input> how can i reference it in data: ? Maybe data:{ "name":"getdata"}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this Problem by changing this

```
  if(request.getParameter("submitdata") != null) {


    if(request.getParameter("getdata") != null) {
        name += request.getParameter("getdata");

    }
}
```

to this

```
String name="";
if(request.getParameter("getdata") != null) {
        name += request.getParameter("getdata");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to send "getdata" and "submitdata" parameters with the ajax.

In your server side code you just send back an empty string if that parameter does not exist:

```
   if(request.getParameter("submitdata") != null) {


        if(request.getParameter("getdata") != null) {
            name += request.getParameter("getdata");

        }
    }
```

Your ajax should look like this:

```
$("#ajaxtest").submit(function(ev) {
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        data.submitdata = true;
        ev.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"InsertServlet",
            dataType: "text",
            data: data

        })
        .done(function(data){
            alert(data);
            $(activeTD).text(data);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Also a `submitdata` parameter.

Comment: @Rupert Thank you for your Answer, but its still empty :( I also have no Error or something, so i really dont know what to do...

Comment: Can you post your HTML? Is `submitdata` the submit button? `serialize()` won't include that, it only gets the data fields from the form.

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="getdata" value=""> and <input value="Speichern" type="submit" name="submitdata" class="btn btn-primary" > oh wow sry for that , i dont know how to format code in comments O..o

Answer (score 0):

Examine the request using a browser utility. It will help you to identify why data is empty.

```
     - Launch the chrome browser 
     - Right click and select inspect element menu
     - click on Network tab
     - Load your URL
     - Perform the Ajax request
     - You can see the request here (new request will be last in the list).
     - Click on it 
     - Right side window shows you request and response data
```

EDIT:

```
$("#ajaxtest").submit(function(ev) {
   var data = $(this).serialize();
   data.submitdata = true;
   ev.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"InsertServlet",
    dataType: "text",
    data: data,
    success:function(data){ // added the success call back
     console.log(data); // check this in browser console
    });
   });
 })
```

Comment: OK the tab post shows : Parameter getdata testdata Source getdata=testdata ,and Respone tab is empty

Comment: This may help you http://www.javatutorials.co.in/servlet-3-ajax-hello-world-example-using-jquery/

Comment: i got an error in the XML tab : XML-Verarbeitungsfehler: Kein Element gefunden Adresse: moz-nullprincipal:{f2c4ef5d-acd5-4ec8-8470-1b9973c1a0c0} Zeile Nr. 2, Spalte 1:

Comment: the Response is now right, but after i submit it is directing me to a blank page with my Input, but i wanted to show this Input on my Table